# Complete object or subobject?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer

The C++14 Standard says:

> A subobject can be a member subobject, a base class subobject, or an array element. An object that is not subobject of any other object is called a complete object. (§1.8(2))

It is not obvious to me whether the 'can be' is meant as an implicit 'if and only if'. To provide an example, in the snippet below, is r a reference to a complete object or to a subobject?

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
  int i=2;
  unsigned char & r=reinterpret_cast<unsigned char&>(i);
  std::cout<<(int)r<<"\n";  
}
```

As r refers to an unsigned char in the object representation , r should refer to an object:

> The object representation of an object of type T is the sequence of N unsigned char objects taken up by the object of type T, ... (§3.9(4))

---

edits: Could you please be very clear about what the first byte of i is:
1) no object at all, 
2) a complete object, 
3) a subobject

There are only these three possibilities.

Comment: The _style_ of the std text is garbage. Always go for intent, not exact words. The words aren't just misleading, they can be false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sentence is defining the term *subobject* as being one of: a *member subobject*, a *base class subobject*, or an array element.

Your snippet has nothing to do with subobjects. `r` is a reference, not an object. Moreover, it doesn't even refer to an object, it simply aliases the first byte of `i`.

From [intro.object]:

> An *object* is created by a definition (3.1), by a *new-expression* (5.3.4), when implicitly changing the active member of a union (9.3), or when a temporary object is created (4.4, 12.2).

`i` is an object created by a definition. As `int` is not a class or array type, it has no subobjects. The object representation, the underlying array of `unsigned char` that constitutes the storage of `i`, is not an object - it's not created in any of those contexts described above. The wording of the definition *object representation* is the subject of [core issue 1701](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1701) (h/t [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108184/complete-object-or-subobject/40108415?noredirect=1#comment67496478_40108415)).

Comment: Here `r` is a complete object, no matter how it is initialized. Right? I mean, is a reference for itself a complete object in any case, even if it's an alias for a subobject?

Comment: ... and the first byte is a complete object.

Comment: @skypjack `r` isn't an object, it's a reference.

Comment: @HeikoBloch No, it's not.

Comment: @Barry Fair enough. The definition doesn't extend to them actually. My fault. Thank you.

Comment: @Barry Then you say the first byte is not an object? How can this be consistent with the definition of 'object representation'?? ('... sequence of N unsigned char objects ...')

Comment: I think there is a slight misunderstanding: The OP did not ask what `r` is, but rather what `r` is _referencing_. `r` aliases the first byte of `i`, so the question becomes: what exactly is the first byte of `i`? An object, a subobject, or what?

Comment: @HeikoBloch I think the standard is off the rails there with its defining 'object representation' in terms of objects. I don't think anyone ever accused the C++ standard of being overly clear and consistent, though.

Comment: @T.C.: If the term "sequence" doesn't imply indexability, what term would be appropriate, given `int foo[10]`, to describe `foo+7`.  I would think it appropriate to say that `foo+7` points to an integer, or a "sequence" of one, two, or three integers, or a degenerate sequence of zero integers, but not that it points to an "array" of two integers.