# Byte-Wise Pointer Arithmetic in sizeof(T) increments: Undefined Behaviour?

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer

Is it undefined behaviour to perform pointer arithmetic on a pointer of type `char *` (that points to an `int` array) in increments of `sizeof(int)` and dereference it later?
E.g. consider the code below. Does it invoke undefined behaviour?

I think the line `/*1*/` should be legal, and `/*2*/` is certainly legal, but I am uncertain about `/*3*/`.

There is a [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39878237/t-versus-char-pointer-arithmetic) that asked something similar, but has no accepted answer.

```
int foo() {
  int arr[10] = {0};
  int i = 4;
  int s = sizeof(int);
  /*1*/ const char * cmem = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&arr[0]);
  /*2*/ cmem += i * s;
  /*3*/ return *reinterpret_cast<const int*>(cmem);
}
```

Comment: It's ok. You also might just do `(arr+i)`

If you have a pointer p1 of type T and a char pointer p2 pointing the same address, then 'p1 + i' is equaled to '*(p2 + i * sizeof(T))'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is OK. It is permitted to do pointer arithmetic within bounds of an object (or one past the end), and the strict aliasing rule allows using an lvalue only differing in `const`-ness from the actual object, to access that object.